# C++: unusual operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, static-cast

What an operator is overloaded here?

`operator T * ()`

I know that the operator method has the following structure:

`type operator operator-symbol ( parameter-list )`

Assume we have the following code

```
template<typename T> class SmartPtr
{
public:
    SmartPtr(T* data): member(data) {}
    T* member;      
    T& operator * () { return *member; }  //usage: *TObj    
    T*& operator () () { return member; }  //usage: TObj()
    operator T * () { return member; }   //usage: ???
};
```

No compilation errors if you try it on the [ideone](http://ideone.com/3yX9na). So what is going on here?

**ADD:** Am I right that `static_cast<T*>(TObj)` makes a call of the `operator T *`? I've tried it [here](http://ideone.com/6oeKCJ).

Comment: It's a conversion operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a *conversion operator*, which allows the class to be converted to `T*`. Usage:

```
T * p = TObj;
```

It's probably a bad idea for a smart pointer to provide this, as it makes it easy to accidentally get a non-smart pointer. Standard smart pointers provide explicit conversion via a `get()` function instead, to prevent accidental conversions.

Comment: +1 How does it work? I.e. under the hood, will it be `static_cast<T*>(member)`? Just curious

Comment: @legends2k: No, there's no cast. It just calls this operator when a conversion is needed; so my usage example is equivalent to `T * p = TObj.operator T *();`, which is equivalent to `T * p = TObj.member;`

Comment: I asked about what happens inside the function i.e. say I've `Circle*` wrapped in the `SmartPtr` trying `int *p = TObj` shouldn't work, right? Why? What really happens to member to become `T*`?

Comment: I wonder a bit, but `static_cast<T*>(member)` call makes the call of this operator. Look at my updated ideone code: http://ideone.com/3yX9na

Comment: @legends2k: Nothing happens to `member`; it's already `T*`, so the operator can simply return it (as it does in the OP's code). The usual conversion rules prevent you from using it to initialise an incompatible pointer type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Aah, completely missed that `T` is the underlying type of the smart pointer, I was imagining some other type `U`. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

This operator is invoked when a `SmartPtr` object appears in an expression, but the compiler has no functions available to resolve the usage made thereof: if it's legal to use a `T*` where the `SmartPtr` appears, the `operator T*()` function is called to generate one.  This means `my_smartptr->my_T_member` can work, as can `f(T*); f(my_smart_ptr_to_T);`.  Similarly, `iostream`s have an `operator bool()` in C++11 (`operator void*()` in C++03 for reasons too tedious to bother with).  It's kind of the opposite of an implicit constructor from a single parameter, where should the compiler not find a valid match using the parameter, it may try to construct an object using that parameter to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
operator T * () { return member; }
```

it is a so-called conversion operator. It converts an object of type SmartPtr to type T *. Moreover it is an implicit conversion opertaor. So when the compiler awaits an object of type T * you can use instead an object of type SmartPtr. 
You could make this conversion operator explicit if you would add keyword explicit. For example

```
explicit operator T * () { return member; }
```